# Java/JTable - Change the size of JTable's scrollbar

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable, where the scrollbars are out of proportion and kind of "get out" from the JTable. How can I adjust this? Check the pics

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks normal to me for nimbus - what aspect are you trying to change?

Comment: Reduce the width, the scrollbars are not set exactly to the Table

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In the constructor **after the function** (normally,`initComponents()`) that initializes the Jtable, just put :

```
this.jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,0));
```

- Note: In my case the variable name of Jtable was jScrollPane1